# unpack_action_data - error: !"unresolvable": env.free. #

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, transfer

I am trying to use unpack_action_data.

```
void apply(const account_name contract, const account_name act) {

        if (act == N(transfer)) {
            transferReceived(eosio::unpack_action_data<currency::transfer>(), contract);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Getting an error:

> 2725650ms thread-0 main.cpp:2493 main ] Failed with error: Assert
>   Exception (10) !"unresolvable": env.free

What header file is missing? I do not see it anywhere